# Problem with iframe and IE6 and IE7 causing extra bottom padding

Tags: css, iframe, internet-explorer-6, internet-explorer-7

I'm trying to insert a Google Maps iframe into my website. The iframe has a padding of 4px and a border of 1px already applied to it but for some reason in IE6 and IE7 there is an extra 3px  padding added to the bottom of the iframe.

You can see my test site here:

http://www.prashantraju.com/test/

Is there a reason why this is occurring and if so is there a fix to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting the following CSS and see if it helps:

```
iframe { 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    padding: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
}

.clear { 
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to do it without hacking, it's simple, put you IFRAME within a DIV.

Example:

```
<div style="width:400px; height:150px;"><iframe 
       width="100%" height="100%"
       marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" 
       style="border: #4EAD18 3px solid"
       name="add" id="add" src="/chatbox/testb.html"></iframe></div>
```

This fix IE6 issue.

Regards.

Oscar

Answer (score 1):

well, this is probably becouse of the elements inside the iframe..
so the simplest way to fix this is by adding overflow: hidden to that iframe like:

```
<iframe style="overflow: hidden;">
```

or with css. lets say that the code is inside a div called googlemap:

```
#googlemap iframe{overflow: hidden;}
```

ie6 and ie7 have problems, so i hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

Near as I can find it's a rendering issue in IE6 and IE7.  Both of those browser's have some interesting quirks when it comes to CSS and it looks like you might have found some.

An option to deal with this quirk would be to conditionally set the padding-bottom for IE6 and IE7 to be 1px instead of 4px.

Kind of hacky but welcome to CSS and IE.

Comment: Ha, we both had the same thought. I know it just feels wrong taking this approach, but its IE6 and IE7. So whatever works right?

Comment: @Doug Agreed sometimes the only way to get it done is going to be something of a hack.  Depending on what I'm trying to line up I just ignore things like this generally.  The clients I work with don't want to pay for that level of nitpicking thank god.

Answer (score 0):

You will often run into problems setting top/bottom padding and a fixed height, or left/right padding and a fixed width. If you are wanting to leave your code as is, you will want to play with something like this. Put it on the page after your `style` block:

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    iframe { padding-right: 2px; padding-bottom: 1px }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

IE 6 and 7 appear to be doubling the bottom padding.  You can test for this by increasing the `padding` to a large number and watching the bottom grow twice the size.  If you subsequently set `padding-bottom: 0`, it will be the right size for these versions of IE.

I can't explain why it's happening.  I think it's probably due to the fact that there is a series of nested iframes inside Google's iframe, but even if you address your frame specifically using id-based CSS, it still happens.

I would simply apply a conditional stylesheet for IE6 and IE7 that sets `padding-bottom: 0`.  Something like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
iframe { padding: 4px ; border: 1px solid #d5d5d5; }
.clear { clear: both; }
</style>
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
<style type="text/css">
iframe { padding-bottom: 0 }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the Google maps page inside the IFrame. I don't know where, and I'm afraid to go into it... It's probably got a MB of CSS or something... in one long line...

If you replace the google page with your own page and a colored background, you'll see that the padding is gone. Giving the google page a colored background <strike>didn't show it, so it's obviously something else on top of that. Probably a bug in the javascript code or some kind of tile positioning code.</strike> **Edit**: It did show a colored background, so that just proves that it is in that page.

Answer (score 0):

I usually start my CSSs with

```
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
}
```

That (universal selector) tells the browsers not to add margin/padding/border by default but to reset it to "0".
It's usually enough to save a lot of trouble with cross-browser issues.

But for this one you're already half-way through, perhaps the best thing to do is to use conditional comments to add an ie6 css and on it add:

```
iframe{
padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This can be caused by whitespace in the document inside the iframe, **including** whitespace between the `<DOCTYPE>` and `<HTML>` element and between the `<HTML>` and the `<HEAD>` element.